# How to get the id of last inserted row using preparedstatement?

Tags: java, mysql, database, postgresql, jdbc

I am using the following code to insert a new row to database, I need to get the id of the last inserted row but when I run the code it shows the following message:

```
SEVERE: java.sql.SQLException: Generated keys not requested. You need to specify   
Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS to Statement.executeUpdate() or 
Connection.prepareStatement().
```

When I use the following code also it gives error although I choose executeUpdate(String sql)

```
  ps.executeUpdate(ps.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
  error >> no suitable method found for executeUpdate(int)
```

the table is as following:

```
       credential 
          int         ID   primary key, auto increment
          varchar(10) name
```

my code

```
String Insert_Credential = "Insert into credential values("
                    + "?,?)";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(Insert_Credential);
            ps.setInt(1, 0);
            ps.setString(2, "username");
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ResultSet generatedKeys = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
        if (generatedKeys.next()) {
             System.out.println("id is"+generatedKeys.getLong(1));
             return generatedKeys.getInt(1);
        } else {
            throw new SQLException("Creating user failed, no generated key obtained.");
        }
```

Comment: Surely it isn't mysql and postgressql?

Comment: @BrianWebster, does not matter what the database is does it ?

Comment: Yes, it matters: There's no ANSI standard way of getting the last inserted id

Comment: @Bohemian But there is in JDBC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ps.executeUpdate(ps.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)
```

You invented that. It doesn't exist.

```
ps = con.prepareStatement(Insert_Credential);
```

That doesn't tell the `PreparedStatement` to return generated keys either. You need this:

```
ps = con.prepareStatement(Insert_Credential, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```