# SQL: Get ID of newly inserted row

Tags: java, sql

I am writing an API, which purpose is it to store data about prisoners in a jail of a minecraft bukkit plugin. I offer a method, that sends a player to jail. When invoked, an entry is made to a database table, which stores all current prisoners. I add a new entry to this table like so:

```java
public static void addNewPunishment(UUID playerUUID, int punishmentBlocks, int maxExtensions) {

        try (final PreparedStatement ps = DatabaseConnector.getConnection().prepareStatement(
                "insert into PRISONERS(UUID, REMAININGBLOCKS, STARTINGBLOCKS, MAXEXTENSIONS) values (?,?,?,?)")) {
            ps.setString(1, playerUUID.toString());
            ps.setInt(2, punishmentBlocks);
            ps.setInt(3, punishmentBlocks);
            ps.setInt(4, maxExtensions);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

However, while implementing methods that use this API it turned out, that it's required, that the id of the newly inserted row is returned, but I have absolutely no idea, how to get it. This is the structure of my table:

[image]

I need the "id"-value of this column, but I can just get the number of affected row's which doesn't really help... How can I make `insert into` return a specific value of the inserted row?

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?

Comment: I'm using MySQl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as described in the link below:

> [How to get the id of last inserted row using preparedstatement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845354/how-to-get-the-id-of-last-inserted-row-using-preparedstatement)

your code could be:

```
public static void addNewPunishment(UUID playerUUID, int punishmentBlocks, int maxExtensions) {

        try (final PreparedStatement ps = DatabaseConnector.getConnection().prepareStatement(
                "insert into PRISONERS(UUID, REMAININGBLOCKS, STARTINGBLOCKS, MAXEXTENSIONS) values (?,?,?,?)"), Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS) {
            ps.setString(1, playerUUID.toString());
            ps.setInt(2, punishmentBlocks);
            ps.setInt(3, punishmentBlocks);
            ps.setInt(4, maxExtensions);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
            if(rs.next())
            {
                    int last_inserted_id = rs.getInt(1);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine, many thanks for the quick response!